# Find moment generating function of sum or random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Problem** Given function $f(x, y) = c(x + y)$ for $0 < x < 2, 0 < y < 2$.

For the first part I had to determine for what value of $c$, $f$ will be the joint density of X and Y. This gave me $c = \frac{1}{8}$.

Then, I had to determine the marginal densities of X and Y. I solved this and received $f_{X}(x) = \frac{1}{4}x + \frac{1}{4}$ and $f_{Y}(y) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}y$.

Next was to calculate the conditional distribution of X given Y $= y_{0}$. I solved it and thus $f_{X|Y}(x|y_{0}) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(x + y_{0})}{(1 + y_{0})}$. Then, $\mathbb{E}[X|Y] = \frac{1}{(1 + y)} \Big (\frac{4}{3} + y \Big )$.

Then I had to determine the distribution function of $\zeta = X + Y$ which resulted in $F_{\zeta}(\xi) = \frac{1}{24} \xi^{3}$

Then the question asked for the second moment which was $\mathbb{E}[X^{2}] = \frac{5}{3}$ and for $Var(3X + 2Y + 1) = \frac{1667}{108}$.

The last question asks for the moment generating function $h_{X + Y}(t)$ such that $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I am stuck on this particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}e^{t\left(X+Y\right)}=\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\left(x+y\right)e^{t\left(x+y\right)}dxdy=\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}xe^{t\left(x+y\right)}dxdy+\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}ye^{t\left(x+y\right)}dxdy$

Observe that the terms are equal by symmetry, so we can proceed with:

$$\cdots=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}ye^{t\left(x+y\right)}dxdy=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2}ye^{ty}\int_{0}^{2}e^{tx}dxdy=\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_{0}^{2}e^{tx}dx\right)\times\left(\int_{0}^{2}ye^{ty}dy\right)=$$$$\frac{1}{4}\left[t^{-1}e^{tx}\right]_{0}^{2}\times\left[t^{-1}ye^{ty}-t^{-2}e^{ty}\right]_{0}^{2}=\frac{1}{4}t^{-3}\left(e^{2t}-1\right)\left(2te^{2t}-e^{2t}+1\right)$$

Check my on mistakes though...

Comment: I think that the last equality should be $\frac{1}{4}t^{-1}(e^{2t} - 1)(2e^{2t} - t^{-1}e^{2t} + t^{-1})$.

Comment: I checked but am sure now that my solution is okay. It can be written as $$\frac{e^{2t}-1}{2t}\times\frac{e^{2t}(2t-1)+1}{2t^2}$$Calculating the limit for $t\to0$ we find $1$ for both factors (here we use rule of l'Hopital once for first factor and twice for second factor) as it should. Because for $t=0$ the MGF equals $1$,